# Why does data get altered while applying a function

Tags: r

I loaded a RDS file. The file contains a numeric field. When I say

```
class(NEI$Emissions)
```

it returns

```
"numeric"
```

The data is in maximum 3 digits and contains 3 digits of decimal. However, when I issue the command

```
max(NEI$Emissions)
```

it returns a huge number.

```
646952
```

How can I use the numeric values as it is?

Comment: How about `hist(NEI$Emissions)`?  My guess is that one of your entries is missing a decimal point in the original source (should have been 646.952)?

Comment: hist(NEI$Emissions) returns a single bar at 0+e0.

Comment: OK, what's `summary(NEI$Emissions)` ?

Comment: summary(NEI$Emissions)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
     0.0      0.0      0.0      3.4      0.1 647000.0

Comment: The evidence heavily favours the idea that you have a single messed up entry.  `summary(NEI$Emissions[NEI$Emissions<1000])` (or the corresponding histogram) should make sense.

Comment: > subset(NEI, Emissions > 100000)
         fips        SCC Pollutant Emissions     type year
4685317 02290 2810001000  PM25-PRI  646952.0 NONPOINT 2002
5077020 41033 2810001000  PM25-PRI  112619.8 NONPOINT 2002

Comment: I cannot provide the output in the format shown on the R Screen.

Answer (score 2):

R doesn't lie.  One of your data points is not what you expect.

Find which row has the problem with this command:

```
which.max(NEI$Emissions)
```

then examine that row of your original data.  You will find the errant value.